# C++ Make file - cannot include Thrift library

Tags: c++, makefile, include, c++17, thrift

I am trying to compile my example Thrift (client-server) program. I've got Thrift installed in the path `$HOME/thrift/lib`, but I cannot resolve why the compiler is giving me errors, that cannot include thrift includes. My make file looks like this:

```
all: client server

# Generate source files from Thrift IDL
gen-cpp/Example.cpp: Example.thrift
    thrift --gen cpp Example.thrift

# Compile server from main source and generated sources
server: server.cpp gen-cpp/Example.cpp
    g++ --std=c++17 -L$HOME/thrift/lib -Igen-cpp:$HOME/thrift/include/thrift -o server server.cpp gen-cpp/Example.cpp -lthrift

# Compile client from main source and generated sources
client: client.cpp gen-cpp/Example.cpp
    g++ --std=c++17 -L$HOME/thrift/lib -Igen-cpp:$HOME/thrift/include/thrift -o client client.cpp gen-cpp/Example.cpp -lthrift

clean:
    rm -f client
    rm -f server
    rm -rf gen-cpp


.PHONY: all clean
```

After I run the make command I get results like this:

```
g++ --std=c++17 -LOME/thrift/lib -Igen-cpp:OME/thrift/include/thrift -o client client.cpp gen-cpp/Example.cpp -lthrift
client.cpp:7:10: fatal error: thrift/protocol/TProtocol.h: No such file or directory
    7 | #include <thrift/protocol/TProtocol.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from gen-cpp/Example.cpp:7:
gen-cpp/Example.h:10:10: fatal error: thrift/TDispatchProcessor.h: No such file or directory
   10 | #include <thrift/TDispatchProcessor.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:13: client] Error 1
```

Do you see something I'm missing or I'm doing wrong? Thank you for all your responses.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the output that make prints when it prints the command line, it's quite obvious there's something wrong:

```
g++ --std=c++17 -LOME/thrift/lib -Igen-cpp:OME/thrift/include/thrift ...
```

What is `-LOME/thrift/lib` and `-Igen-cpp:OME/thrift/include/thrift`?  Those can't possibly be right: those directories don't exist.  So, clearly there's something wrong in your makefile, with the recipe you're using:

```
g++ --std=c++17 -L$HOME/thrift/lib -Igen-cpp:$HOME/thrift/include/thrift ...
```

And indeed, there is.  The `$` is special to make: it introduces make variables.  If you want to use `$` so it's passed to the shell in your recipes, you have to escape it by doubling it: `$$`.

If you rewrite your recipe like this:

```
g++ --std=c++17 -L$$HOME/thrift/lib -Igen-cpp:$$HOME/thrift/include/thrift ...
```

then you'll see that make will invoke the command with the single unescaped `$`:

```
g++ --std=c++17 -L$HOME/thrift/lib -Igen-cpp:$HOME/thrift/include/thrift ...
```

and it will work.  Alternatively, you could use the make variable here, but then you have to enclose it in `()` or `{}` (they are the same):

```
g++ --std=c++17 -L$(HOME)/thrift/lib -Igen-cpp:$(HOME)/thrift/include/thrift ...
```

Comment: I have to say I don't know what the `gen-cpp:` prefix is.  I've not seen that before.  Maybe it's something specific to your tools?

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, I fixed that. `gen-cpp` is a directory where additional thrift c++ code is generated for my example work.  Then I used `:` to separate the directories that should be included. But as I escaped the `$$` it still cannot include `#include <thrift/protocol/TProtocol.h>`

Comment: As far as I'm aware it's not legal to separate paths with `:` in a single `-I` option.  If you want to add two different directories, you have to write two different options: `-Igen-cpp -I$$HOME/thrift/...`

Comment: The path in your `#include` is added to each path given with each `-I` and the file is checked.  So, if you have `#include <thrift/protocol/TProtocol.h>` and you have `-Igen-cpp -I$HOME/thrift/include/thrift`, then the compiler will search for the files `gen-cpp/thrift/protocol/TProtocol.h` and `$HOME/thrift/include/thrift/thrift/protocol/TProtocol.h`.  Neither of those exists.  I assume that if you're going to add `thrift/...` in your `#include`, you should NOT add it in your `-I`.  So, it should be `-I$$HOME/thrift/include` instead.